# Google Web Designer Polite Load

Tags: image-preloader, google-web-designer

Just started using GWD - not too bad. I have most of it under control, (actually usually end up going through DreamWeaver to edit the code directly instead of GWD), but cannot figure out how to set up the Polite Load loading image. Anyone know how to fill in these blanks using image `logo1.png`? I've tried numerous things but it always tanks the whole deal.

Here's the related section of the initialization code Google provides:

```
      /**
       * Handles the event that is dispatched after the Ad has been
       * initialized and before the default page of the Ad is shown.
       */
      function handleAdInitialized(event) {
        // This marks the end of the polite load phase of the Ad. If a
        // loading image was shown to the user, this is a good place to
        // remove it.
      }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
        handleDomContentLoaded, false);
      window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',
        handleWebComponentsReady, false);
      window.addEventListener('adinitialized',
        handleAdInitialized, false);
    })();
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Google documentation](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/6057545), you should put a <div> containing your loading image after your <body> tag:

```
<body style="visibility: hidden;">
  <div id="loading" class="loading-image">
  <img src="logo1.png">
  </div>
  <gwd-doubleclick id="gwd-ad" polite-load="">
  ...
  </gwd-doubleclick>
</body>
```

Then in the handleAdInitialised function, remove or hide the image <div>:

```
function handleAdInitialised(event) {
  // This marks the end of the polite load phase of the Ad. If a
  // loading image was shown to the user, this is a good place to
  // remove it.
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The only issue you'll find here is it might mess up your preview in Google Web Designer.

So currently I'm adding some CSS in the code view to hide the loading image from the GWD stage preview:

```
/* CSS: HIDE OUR LOADING IMAGE */
<style>
.loading-image {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

And then in my main runtime function I'm setting the display attribute to "block" to bring it back again.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="gwd-init-code">
  (function() {
    document.body.style.opacity = "0";

    // SHOW OUR LOADING IMAGE AGAIN
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
```

I think this should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes I have the code that you show from the google link you provided aleady in the file, my challenge is when I am editing this code in DreamWeaver I cannot get any loading image to show up during a preview without tanking the whole sequence.Where do I identify the loading image to use? Using 'logo1.png' as an example loading image, where does it go? Also, "loading-image" does not come up in the class list.

Comment: Do you by chance have a snippet of working code showing the correct syntax for the loading and exiting of polite load?

Comment: updated code above. i'm not sure what you mean by tanking the whole sequence. my loading-image class i added manually to the end of the css that GWD creates. 

i then set this class to display:none so it's not visible in the editor. Then i set it to display:block when the code runs (in the gwd-init-code)

here's the full code example
http://pastebin.com/nJ0qYeyJ

Answer (score 1):

Just started using GWD too and i have the same question.
Gwd set body opacity to "0" beacuse of that loding img is not shown.In the "gwddoubleclick_min.js" gwd set body opacity.

```
document.body.style.opacity="0"
```

I changed;

```
document.getElementById("gwd-ad").style.opacity="0"
```

And after every element loaded,in the same file;

```
document.body.style.opacity=""
```

changed;

```
document.getElementById("gwd-ad").style.opacity="",
document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none'
```

It worked for me.
Has anyone get different solution?

Answer (score 0):

As Burak Şahin Erden has answered before me, GWD is setting the body opacity to "0" which in turn hides the preLoad div.

Adding the code he mentioned seems to be the only way around this, my ad works as expected now with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="gwd-init-code">
(function() {
  document.getElementById("gwd-ad").style.opacity="0"
  document.body.style.opacity=""

  var gwdAd = document.getElementById('gwd-ad');

  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';

  /**
   * Handles the DOMContentLoaded event. The DOMContentLoaded event is
   * fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed.
   */
  function handleDomContentLoaded(event) {}

  /**
   * Handles the WebComponentsReady event. This event is fired when all
   * custom elements have been registered and upgraded.
   */
  function handleWebComponentsReady(event) {
    // Start the Ad lifecycle.
    setTimeout(function() {
      gwdAd.initAd();
    }, 0);
  }

  /**
   * Handles the event that is dispatched after the Ad has been
   * initialized and before the default page of the Ad is shown.
   */
  function handleAdInitialized(event) {
    document.getElementById("gwd-ad").style.opacity="",
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none'
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    handleDomContentLoaded, false);
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',
    handleWebComponentsReady, false);
  window.addEventListener('adinitialized',
    handleAdInitialized, false);
})();
```

Comment: I have just realised this solution doesn't work as expected in Firefox and Safari, only Chrome - Body is still getting opacity "0" applied